# More elegant/efficient numerical WKB implementation for 1D Schrödinger Equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, physics

I'm trying to figure out a better way to implement numerical WKB quantization of a spectrum. WKB quantization is the condition that

$$\oint_{E}p \, \mathrm{d}q = \pi \hbar (n+1/2)$$

So the idea to implement it numerically is to do the integral over and over again for different values of $E$ and when it turns out to be a half-integer multiple of $2 \pi \hbar$ I take the corresponding value of $E$ to be in the spectrum.

Here's how it's implemented. The integral is rescaled so that it is always on the interval $(-1,1)$ and the energy can be related to the value `a` used to do this rescaling:

```
h = 1; m = 2; xmax = 10; nMax = 87;
Vv[x_] := x^2/2 + 0.375 x^4;

action = Table[{a, 
Re[NIntegrate[a Sqrt[2 m (Vv[a] - Vv[a x])], {x, -1, 1}]]}, 
    {a, 0.000001, xmax/2, 0.005}];

curve = Interpolation @ action;

allowedEnergies = a /. Table[
   FindRoot[ curve[a] == π h (n - 1/2), {a, 1, 2}], {n, 1, nMax}];

ListPlot @ allowedEnergies
```

Is there a better (or even built-in) way to implement this? I think this way of going about it is pretty hacky and inelegent.

Comment: Note, by the way, that your `allowedEnergies` are not actually the allowed energies. You've got to "unscale" them by working backwards to get the turning points, and then plug the turning points back into V to get the real energies. That will turn your square-root-ish looking energies into something else.

Comment: Actually, the way you've parameterized things, `a` *is* the turning point, and so you just need to plug it back into the potential to get the actual energy.

Comment: I actually like your implementation. What do you want to improve?

Answer (score 3):

I think we can do direct root-finding by defining a numerical function for your integration variable, like so:

```
ClearAll@f
f[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a Sqrt[2 m (Vv[a] - Vv[a x])], {x, -1, 1}]
```

Then we can root-find on this function using `FindRoot`, i.e.

```
Table[a /. FindRoot[f[a] == π (n + 1/2), {a, n}], {n, 0, 5}]
(* {0.75565, 1.18227, 1.43771, 1.62971, 1.78691, 1.92165} *)
```

If you compare these values to what you get, it's actually very similar, but this method is much faster. Note that you might want to tweak the initial guesses to get better convergence, and *Mathematica* does spit out some errors, so you want to be careful with the method to make sure that you can trust the results.